# Unable to create a calculated field or measure in Jaspersoft adhoc view

Tags: jasperserver

According to this help document

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/v56/creating-calculated-field

I should be able to create a calculated field or measure for a Jaspersoft Adhoc view. However I don't seem to have this functionality available to me since I don't have the icon required to click on to create these things. Does anyone know if this is a new feature or whether this has something to do with restrictions on functionality due to licencing or something? Is there another way to create a calculated measure that I can use as a work around considering I don't have the correct icon to enable this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of JasperReports Server are you in? You can chek this in the login page, on the bottom left corner there is an About Jaspersoft link. There you can also check the license type.
This feature is available only for commercial edition.
So I guess you are a customer: have you tried reaching out to Jaspersoft support?
https://support.jaspersoft.com

Comment: I'm using version 5.2 and this feature is not available on 5.2. It is also no longer supported.